# Trying to pass an argument to a method on tap gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an array of images I am generating programatically. On each image, I am adding a tap gesture. What I want to happen, is when that image is tapped, for the border to become black.

At the moment, and am trying to pass an argument to the method that will then find the image in the array list. I am struggling to find the right syntax to pass that argument though

Here is the code. Any help is appreciated!

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int  recents = 10;

    int x = 10;

    _recent.contentSize = CGSizeMake((x*120)+10,100 );
   for(int i = 0; i <=recents; i ++){

  _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 10, 90, 90)];

       [_arrayImages addObject:_imageView];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        _imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        _imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        _imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 45.0;
        _imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        _imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
        _imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        _imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
      NSUInteger * count;
        _imageView.tag = i;

       UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
       [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapImageWithGesture:)];
       tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
       [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];




        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 110, 90, 24)];
        label.text = @"Sam Stone";
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:62/255.0f green:68/255.0f blue:75/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
       [_recent addSubview:_imageView];
       [_recent addSubview:label];
        [_arrayImages addObject:_imageView];
           x=x+110;
    }


}
- (void)didTapImageWithGesture:(id)sender {

    UIImageView *image;
    image = [_arrayImages objectAtIndex:((UIGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag];
    image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing something, but this should be simpler.  We have N image views and N gesture recognizers, one attached to each.  The method signature for a gesture recognizer is like this:

```
- (void)didTapImageWithGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    // want the view?
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)gr.view;

    // want the image?
    UIImage *image = imageView.image;

    // want the index of the imageView in the array?
    // not sure why you'd want this. all it tells you is the z-order
    NSInteger index = [_arrayImages indexOfObject:imageView];

    // want the view again?
    UIImageView *imageViewAgain = _arrayImages[index];
    // but why?  you already have the view

    // does
    if (imageViewAgain == imageView) // of course it's true!
}
```

Notice that we didn't need to refer to a tag or the position of the tap at all.  Now, if we had tagged the views.  We could also say:

```
NSInteger tag = gr.view.tag;
UIImageView *imageViewAgainAgain = _arrayImages[tag];
```

Or we could say:

```
UIImageView *imageViewAgainAgainAgain = [gr.view.superview viewWithTag:tag];
```

But again, this is like getting a ride from a crooked Paris cab driver, driving you in byzantine circles, just running up the meter.

Answer (score 1):

Add a tag to the tap gesture which tells the image view index, in the tap action you would get the sender, from which you can get the tag value thereby image view.

In your code, add a tag to gesture recognizer.

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
   [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapImageWithGesture:)];
   tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   tapGesture.tag = i; 
   [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Comment: I've edited my above code to how I I've interpreted the two answers. Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your question.